# Why option of include project not showing in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Thank you so much guys for your previous support on many issues...
I have started to work on MVC 4 in asp.net.
I had tried to setup a template of bootstrap in project. I have copied all the required folder in project but i am not able to access the sub folder and files.

[image]

You have seen in the above image. Know i want to access them so any one help me that what should i do to access their internal folders and files...

Note: If this question is not valid then do not devote me you can comment then i will delete this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Show All Files button?